# How can I add a page number to the right corner of the page?

Tags: header-footer, margins

I used to use `\pagestyle{fancy}` to make my page number be placed at the right bottom corner, but there is a problem that it only can be placed at the inside of the page margin, I want to move it to the very bottom of the page.
Let me show you:

[image]

Comment: Would you show us how you obtained the current output?

Comment: Did you try \fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{\marginnote{\colorbox{red!50!black} {\color{white}\thepage}} ?

Answer (score 5):

If you can use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr` you can define new layers and add them to the predefined page styles `scrheadings` and `plain`.

```
\documentclass[
%  twoside
]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  oddpage,
  align=br,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  voffset=\paperheight,
  width=7em,
  height=2\baselineskip,
  contents={{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \colorbox{red!50!black}{\parbox[c][\layerheight][c]{\layerwidth}{\centering\pagemark}}%
  }}
]{pagenumberouterbottom.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=pagenumberouterbottom.odd,
  evenpage,
  align=bl,
  hoffset=0pt
]{pagenumberouterbottom.even}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}\bfseries}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumberouterbottom.odd,pagenumberouterbottom.even}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain}{pagenumberouterbottom.odd,pagenumberouterbottom.even}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the code is also a layer for even pages. So if the document is twosided the page number will be on the outer margin.

With `twoside`:

[image]

Comment: but if i use titlesec in this article，there will be a "Package scrlayer Error define '\newpagestyle'" problem .

Comment: There was no MWE in your question. But you can use `\usepackage[forceoverwrite]{scrlayer-scrpage}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.anicca-vijja.de/2009/05/latex-put-page-numbers-out-of-the-margin/) via google and played a little around. To shift margins as such (e.g. footer lower) you can use the geometry package.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\lefoot{
 \hspace{-5em}\pagemark\headmark
}
\rofoot{
 \headmark\pagemark\hspace{-5em}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrpage2` is obsolete and should be replaced by `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: That's the which I was used , but i still think it is not the best solution