# scrreprt: Control the position of page number with respect to margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering, koma-script

I would like to put the page number exactly `1 cm` above the page bottom border (midway between margin and page border) and `2 cm` left to the right page border (exactly on the right margin).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,
top=2cm,
bottom=2cm,
left=4cm,
right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

---

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: Package `scrlayer-scrpage` can help you. We already have a question like that, let me take a quick search.

Comment: [How cloud i add a page number to the right corner of the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294399)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am a bit confused. Where can I find the code piece that controls the bottom and right offset from the page borders?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, can you provide me with any answered question to understand how to apply your comment in my case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,
top=2cm,
bottom=1cm,
includefoot,
left=4cm,
right=2cm,
footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\cofoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter Title}

    \lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and flawless :). I highly appreciate your swift consideration.